# C# Why can't I access domain user's local folder under C:\Users?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a laptop connected to a domain named Homebase, where I have a domain user (Jamie L. Horton) logged in. On that laptop I also have a local account named Jamie which I don't use, but I'd rather not delete it. The problem is I am trying to access my domain user's local Download folder.

If I look under C:\Users it shows a folder for Jamie and one for Jamie.HOMEBASE. If I try to access this folder in C# "C:\Users\Jamie.HOMEBASE" it throws a Directory Not Found Exception. If I look at all the folders under C:\Users in C# I do NOT see Jamie.HOMEBASE, but only one folder named Jamie. Which I checked whats inside and it is indeed the local user Jamie and not the domain user.

What's going on? How come I can access this folder in windows explorer with that path, but not with C#?

Comment: How do you access it? Can you show your code?

Comment: Just with 'var AllFiles = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Jamie.HOMEBASE\", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);'

Comment: Try var AllFiles = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Users\Jamie.HOMEBASE\"); and see what you get.

Comment: Already did, still nothing. What is really puzzling to me is that in c# all the folders in C:\Users there is no folder named Jamie.HOMEBASE, but I can see it in windows explorer

Comment: Are there any directories in Jamie.HOMEBASE? What version of Windows is this? Are you running your VS as administrator?

Comment: Yes there are directories in Jamie.HOMEBASE, I'm on windows 10 64bit, while using VS 2015 not as administrator, also I am using it as a remoteapp on a windows 2012 r2 server.

Comment: 2 things. Not running VS as an admin and trying to access a domain user folder will not work. Also if you are running VS remotely, there is a very high possibility that the way remote server sees your directory structure is different from what you see in the explorer. So build your exe( if it's an exe) then execute it with admin privileges on your local machine and see the result.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just run the program as admin as soon as I can to see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kosala W. said "Not running VS as an admin and trying to access a domain user folder will not work." The fix for me was to run VS as an admin and the problem was fixed.